# AES_ENCRYPT() and AES_DECRYPT not working properly to store values in mysql using xampp server and python flask

Tags: python, mysql, sql, cryptography, aes

I am learning python flask and developing a web page where I can register and store user details in encrypted format in MySQL database using XAMPP server and decrypting the same to verify user details during login.

Here, while storing the encrypted password in database, the `AES_ENCRYPT` function is encrypting the string 'password' itself and not the one that is entered in the form. And the `AES_DECRYPT` function does not retrieve back the string during login verification, so, it always shows invalid password. How to resolve this?

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

import mysql.connector as MySQLdb

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/login')
def login():
    return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/register')
def register():
    return render_template('register.html')

def valid_login(uname, password):
    # Open database connection
    db = MySQLdb.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        passwd="",
        database="sam"
    )

    cursor = db.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT AES_DECRYPT(AES_ENCRYPT('passcode', 'usa2010'), 'usa2010') FROM user WHERE username = %s"

    value =(uname, )
    cursor.execute(sql, value)
    row = cursor.fetchone()

    print(row[0])
    if password == row[0].decode():
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

    # disconnect from server
    db.close()

def valid_insert(uname, email, password, phone, city):
    # Open database connection
    db = MySQLdb.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        passwd="",
        database="sam"
    )
    cursor = db.cursor()
    sql = "INSERT INTO user VALUES (%s, %s, AES_ENCRYPT(password, 'usa2010'), %s, %s)"

    val = (uname, email, phone, city)
    cursor.execute(sql, val)
    db.commit()

    if cursor.rowcount > 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

    # disconnect from server
    db.close()

@app.route('/check', methods=['POST'])
def check():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if valid_login(request.form['uname'], request.form['pass']):
            return render_template('home.html')
        else:
            print('Invalid username/password')
    return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/login_insert', methods=['POST'])
def insert():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if valid_insert(request.form['uname'], request.form['email'], request.form['pass'], request.form['phone'], request.form['city']):
            return render_template('login.html')
        else:
            error = 'Username already taken.'
    return render_template('register.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: look you don't want to decrypt the passwords of users, you only store a hash and check the input against it, that is secure as long the algorithm is secure see https://pythonprogramming.net/password-hashing-flask-tutorial/

Comment: Please **do not shout**, use "thank you"s or smileys and such. Instead, try and write better sentences, use capitalization where required. If you put your text and question on top then it will be better received; people don't like to start reading swaths of code before getting to a question.

Comment: This is a problem with SQL, not python. I'm submitting an edit to add that flag.